# ¿Por qué nunca entra en el if?

Tags: java, archivo

Estoy leyendo un fichero por acceso aleatorio. El fichero esta relleno con datos que he almacenado en arrays(cuatro registros).

Lo que quiero hacer es que el usuario pueda buscar una palabra dentro del archivo y una vez lo encuentre imprima los datos de ese registro.

Este es el método que uso para crear el fichero:

```
  public static void crearFicheroAlea() {
            File fichero = new File("ficheroequipo.dat");
            try {
                RandomAccessFile alea = new RandomAccessFile(fichero, "rw");
    
                //VARIABLES:
                String[] nomEquipo = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"};
    
                String[] localidad = {"Telde", "Las Palmas", "Ingenio", "Arinaga", "Mogan", "Carrizal", "Puerto Rico", "Valsequillo", "Ojos de Garza", "Las Remudas"};
    
                double[] presupuesto = {900.0, 850.0, 1200.0, 1540.0, 1300.0,
                    960.0, 1240.0, 1800.0, 1000.0, 1600.0};
    
                int[] num_jugadores = {11, 10, 13, 4, 15, 9, 7, 18, 6, 12};
    
                StringBuffer buf = null;
                StringBuffer buf2 = null;
    
                for (int i = 0; i < num_jugadores.length; i++) {
    
                    buf = new StringBuffer(nomEquipo[i]);
                    buf.setLength(35);
                    buf2 = new StringBuffer(localidad[i]);
                    buf2.setLength(25);
                    alea.writeChars(buf.toString());
                    alea.writeChars(buf2.toString());
                    alea.writeInt(num_jugadores[i]);
                    alea.writeDouble(presupuesto[i]);
                }
                alea.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error al crear el fichero");
            }
        }
```

Luego tengo el método para buscar en este caso por nombre de equipo una vez en el método main haya creado el archivo y pedido el nombre del equipo que quiere buscar al usuario:

```
static String vnombre;
    static String vlocalidad;
    static int num_jugadores;
    static double presupuesto;
    static boolean existeEquipo;

    public static void buscarEquipo(String equipo) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        File fichero = new File("ficheroequipo.dat");
        RandomAccessFile alea = new RandomAccessFile(fichero, "rw");
        try {
            int pos = 0;//4
            char localidad[] = new char[25];//50
            char nombreEquipo[] = new char[35];//70
            existeEquipo = false;

            while (true) {
                alea.seek(pos);

                for (int i = 0; i < nombreEquipo.length; i++) {
                    nombreEquipo[i] = alea.readChar();
                }
                vnombre = new String(nombreEquipo);//2*35
                System.out.println(equipo);
                System.out.println(vnombre);
                if (vnombre.equals(equipo)) {

                    for (int y = 0; y < localidad.length; y++) {
                        localidad[y] = alea.readChar();
                    }
                    vlocalidad = new String(localidad);//2*25
                    num_jugadores = alea.readInt();//4
                    presupuesto = alea.readDouble();//8
                    existeEquipo = true;
                    System.out.println("\nNombre del equipo: " + vnombre + "\nLocalidad: " + vlocalidad + "\nNº de jugadores: " + num_jugadores + "\nPresupuesto: " + presupuesto);
                }

                //total de bytes por registro 132
                pos = pos + 132;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        alea.close();
       /* if (existeEquipo == true) {
            System.out.println("\nNombre del equipo: " + vnombre + "\nLocalidad: " + vlocalidad + "\nNº de jugadores: " + num_jugadores + "\nPresupuesto: " + presupuesto);
        } else {
            System.out.println("El nombre del equipo no fue encontrado.");
        }*/
    }
```

He hecho el sout de vnombre y equipo para verificar que las dos variables guardan la misma cadena antes de ser comparadas.

Agradezco de antemano la respuesta.

Comment: Ese while (true) ¿cuando termina? no veo su break; Es aconsejable salir del while con false.

Comment: Tienes razón. Lo que hago es un bucle infinito de esta manera me aseguro que siempre lance IOExeption y al estar vacio el catch no lanza mensaje de error pero me debe leer el bucle.